# Injective map from subset of all infinite binary sequences into $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, binary, geometric-series

I have been attempting to prove that the following map $f$ is one-to-one.

$f:A\rightarrow B$

where

$A$ is the set of all all infinite binary sequences (for example, $(0,1,0,0,0,1,...)\in A$) with the exception of sequences that end with an infinite trail of zeros and contain at least one "$1$."

$B = [0,1]$

and $f(a_1,a_2,a_3,...) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\frac{a_i}{2^i})$ (where $a_i = 0$ or $1$).

However, I have only been able to show that $1 - \sum_{i=0}^{n} = \frac{1}
{2^n}$ implies that, for instance, ordered pairs $(0,1,0,0,0,0,...)\notin A$ and $(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,...)\in A$ produce the same value when input to $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\frac{a_i}{2^i})$.

How can one complete this proof?  Any recommendations or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your function is not one-to-one. E.g., 0.011011...  = 0.01110... You need to eliminate all binary expansions other than 0.00... that involve an infinite string of zeros.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Thank you for the correction (the post has now been edited). How would one show that the corrected version of the function is one to one?

Comment: Well suppose $f(a) = f(b)$ for some sequences $a$ and $b$. What can you say about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Rob Arthan Exactly two possibilities for the values of each $a$ and $b$ exist? When we eliminate the possibilites not in $A,$ only one possibility exists?